# How can I prevent an image to hide outside borders

Tags: javascript

So I am currently building a video game where my image is moving with keyboard controllers. The issue is that this icon goes out of the screen borders. Does someone knows how to deal with this (js or css only please)? Thanks

Icon moving with controllers:

```
let display = document.getElementById("body").style.width
let rect = document.getElementById("icon-p1")
let pos = {top: 85, left: 600}
const keys = {}
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {keys[e.keyCode] = true})
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {keys[e.keyCode] = false})
const loop = function() {
if (keys[37] || keys[81]) {pos.left -= 10; if (display < 100) {pos.left -= 0}}
if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {pos.left += 10; if (display < 100) {pos.left += 0}}
if (keys[38] || keys[90]) {pos.top -= 1; if (display < 100) {pos.top -= 0}}
if (keys[40] || keys[83]) {pos.top += 1; if (display < 100) {pos.top += 0}}
rect.style.left = pos.left + "px"; rect.style.top = pos.top + "%"}
let sens = setInterval(loop, 1000 / 40)
```

Css for background image:

```
body {
background-image: url(Photo/bg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: if left < 0, than don't move left;
if left + width > screen width, then dont move right;
Do the same for vertical movement

Comment: Okay thanks but could you please provide some piece of code?

Comment: Any luck with the solution?

Comment: Yep thanks it worked

Comment: Nice! I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer. I'm pretty close to a reputation milestone!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the box is far enough away from the boundries:

```js
// just storing the movement increment in a variable to make code softer
let moveInc = 10; 

// this is the width of the boundary. If the boundary/container has a width of 600px, this will be 600.
let containerWidth = document.getElementById("yourContainerID/screenID").style.width;

// this is the height of the boundary. If the boundary/container has a height of 800px, this will be 800.
let containerHeight = document.getElementById("yourContainerID/screenID").style.height;

// here is the function from your code
const loop = function() {

    // you will be better off formatting your code to match mine (aka no one-liner if statements)
    if (keys[37] || keys[81]) {
        if (pos.left > 0 + moveInc)// 0 is the left boundary, and the moveInc will act as a buffer to stop any overlap with the left boundary
            pos.left -= moveInc;
    }
    if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {
        if (pos.left + rect.style.width < containerWidth - moveInc)// containerWidth is the right boundary, again moveInc is a buffer
            pos.left += moveInc;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can use the same principal for top and bottom.

Top will be comparable to left

Bottom will be comparable to right

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not going to work. I'll update my answer to have more detail.